# Slow Build Time on Brand New ASP.NET Core 2.1 Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, build, asp.net-core-2.1

I have created a brand new ASP.NET Core 2.1 Application in visual studio 15.7.3.

The build time for a freshly created app is extremely slow at about 20seconds.

Tracing the build as best I can it seems to stall here:

```
1>    C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.extensions\2.1.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Extensions.dll
1>    '
1>    Server execution failed with response Rejected. For more info, check 
the server log file in the location specified by the RAZORBUILDSERVER_LOG 
environment variable.
1>    Fallback to in-process execution.
```

Surely this cant be normal, anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a bug if you have spaces in your username - see https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/issues/2406

The solution that worked for me was to put the following in my csproj file

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <!-- see https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/issues/2406 -->
  <_RazorBuildServerPipeName>razor-issues-2406</_RazorBuildServerPipeName>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: TL;DR: This fix will only benefit you if your username has a space in it. Mine doesn't, and it didn't.

Comment: @Daz Did you add your info the the github issue?

Comment: I've updated the answer to make it clearer where it will work - thanks @Daz